# visual studio 2013 command line parameter compile for xp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, windows-xp, libcurl

I'm currently developing an application on visual studio 2013 which works fine on Windows Vista+ but I need to make it work on Windows XP.

So I compiled it using the  visual studio 2013 Windows XP (v120_xp) toolset. and it worked fine. But then I got errors indicating that my library weren't compatible for XP ( libcurl).

I suppose I need to compile it with the same toolset but I can't find anywhere the parameter I need to set so it uses the v12_xp toolset.

I compiled the lib using :

```
nmake /f MakeFile.vc mode=static DEBUG=yes
```

and

```
nmake /f MakeFile.vc mode=static DEBUG=no
```

Thanks in advance :)